# Xcode & Firebase - I'd want an app feature wherein a menu tab selects which data to fetch within the controller

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently creating a school app which has a feature that allows users to select an organization logo on the menu bar of a certain CollectionView Controller which fetches news given by the selected organization. The main screen shows all of the news prior to selecting an organization before it shows specific news (All of this happens in one CollectionView Controller). However, I'm quite confused onto how should I write the data on the database inline with easily retrieving it on xcode. Should I write it how it is normally done; like:

1. news

   - -k1hfdsfs1- (random post key)

     - Title: Pep Rally Tomorrow
     - createdDate: 15992992
     - Organization: Football Team
   - -kf1343df- (random post key)

     - Title: School Elections
     - createdDate: 15992992
     - Organization: Student Council

Then fetch the data based on the name, "Organization"?

Or should I be more specific when writing to the database? and create different random keys for the different organizations but still under the news parent. But would I still be able to show all the news in the main screen when it starts up? 
are there other approaches for this kind of situation? Thank you so much.

NOTE:
I use javascript to post data to the firebase database and use swift to retrieve and fetch data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach of designing your db structure can be ->

```
{
    "organization1" : {
        "news":{
        "1496431915949(random post key)" : {
          "title" : "Pep Rally Tomorrow",
          "author" : "Mr Stuart",
          "organizationName" : "Football Team",
          "createdDate" : "15992992"},
        "1496432087873" : {
            "title" : "School Sports Meet",
            "author" : "Coach",
            "organizationName" : "Football Team",
            "createdDate" : "15992994"}
      }
        },"organization2" : {
                "news":{}
            },
            "organization3" : {
                "news":{}
            }
        }
```

In this way you can fetch all the Organizations from firebase and show a list also -

Comment: Thanks for the reply tekgy! So would it be possible that in the main screen a mix of all the news from all organization will be shown in the list? If so, what is the best way to fetch all the news?, would that mean i skip the organization parent and proceed to "news" in my code? or is there a specific way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: What you can do is get all the child of root node which will give you list of Organizations Json. Then form each child you can fetch the last 2 or 3 latest items and display it in the news section of the app.